# Display an int number in hexadecimal with leading zeros

Tags: c, hex, printf

I read an integer data like `ABCD` with `fscanf(file_input, "%X", &data);`

There is no problem here, if my number has exactly 4 groups != 0

For example if a read `0002` it displays me only `2`, or for `00AB` it gives me `AB`

I display it with `printf("%X", data);`

Is there something to print with exactly 4 groups even if they are zeros?

I tried `printf("%4X", &data);` but it moves my result with 4 spaces right.

Could you please help me?

Comment: `printf("%04X", data);` I believe that's what you want

Comment: actualy i read with `fscanf(file_input, "%X", &data)`, the problem is not the file from where i read, but the output, it gives me 2 instead of 0002

Comment: yes the printf with %04X it works, thank you !!!

Comment: Note: if `data` is `int` additional issues occur.  Better to use `unsigned`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `printf()` and friends a field specifier such as `%X` can take a *width* parameter. For a field width of 4 this would be

```
printf("%4X", data);
```

and it is padded with spaces on the left. If you wanted it padded on the right it would be

```
printf("%-4X", data);
```

To be padded with zeros, it is done like this

```
printf("%04X", data);
```

Answer (score 2):

to display in 4 groups with starting zeros as I guess you need. 
Use this:

```
printf("%04x",data);
```